# How to display data series label in google sheets charts

Tags: google-apps-script, charts, google-sheets

I made a google Apps script to modify a chart and I would like to display the data label of the series number 0 but the line `.setOption('series',{ 1:{color: '#2ecc71'}})` (where I change the color of the series 1) remove the data label of the series 0.

```
      var Vmax =1.1*ss.getRangeByName("D285").getValue(); //get max and min here (before, it's equal to 0)
      var Vmin =0.9*ss.getRangeByName("C285").getValue(); 
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var chart = sheet.getCharts()[46];
      chart = chart.modify()
        .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.AREA)
        .setOption('title',string)
        .setOption('vAxes', {0: {textStyle: {fontSize: 10}, titleTextStyle: {fontSize : 8}, viewWindow: {min: Vmin, max:Vmax}}})
        .setOption('series',{ 1:{color: '#2ecc71'}})
        .setOption('titleTextStyle',{alignment:"center"})
        .setOption('animation.startup',true)
        .setOption('animation.duration', 5000)
        .setOption('hAxis.slantedText',true)
        .setPosition(290,6,0,0)
        .build();
        Logger.log(Vmax);
        Logger.log(Vmin);
      sheet.updateChart(chart);
```

[This is what I have :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YD5n.png)

[And this is what I want :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDNKa.png)

Comment: Hi, could you please share your sheet, or a copy to better visualize what you mean and better test the code?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but the screenshots you added to the question help a lot!

Comment: I made a copy of it here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JBEcCQQrC8fHgnrLcyxmGFP-4BlIDFZgjlCHIAMeLNU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: could you make it editable so I can go into the script? otherwise I can't see it

Comment: You should be able to edit it now

Comment: those labels are referred to as "annotations" and are added via an [annotation column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#annotationrole) to the data table -- however, I don't believe column roles are available in apps script...

Comment: Thanks, it is possible to change the annotations paramaters with the function setOption() as listed in this link : https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart#configuration-options
But I can't figure out what I have to change.

Comment: You should take a look at Chart With Explicit Column Roles in [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#what-are-roles), it shows an example of how to set the annotations

Comment: I already looked at this documentation but I wanted to update the chart and not delete it to create a new one. But I think it's the only way..
Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

Your comments helped me solve this problem. I didn't know that the key word is annotations.

here is the code I used to update the dataLabel font and color

```
.setOption("series", {1 : {dataLabel: "value"}}) //this creates the data label
.setOption("series", {1: {annotations: {textStyle : {fontSize : 24, color : 'white'}}}}) //this updates the color and font size of the data label.
```

I run this through updateChart

I hope this helps

Comment: I should note, I use this with an embedded chart. but I believe it will be the same or similar for standalone charts service. the parent child relationships are the same.